# Iterate through a list of elements and check for existence of custom data attribute containing a value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

My pseudocode looks like this:

```
for (class='delivery') {
  if (i[date ~= 'Tomorrow']) {
    i.append(<div>50p</div>)
  }
  else {
    i.append(<div>FREE</div>)
  }
}
```

So in other words, I want to generate a list (array or object, whatever works) of nodes with a certain class name, and as I iterate through them I want to say 'if the custom data attribute of 'date' (that they all have) contains 'Tomorrow' I append a div containing '50p', or else I append a div containing 'FREE'. I can do this with JS or Jquery.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is not a coding service. It's good that you have made your pseudocode but now you should start by trying to make your code look ever each element with class `delivery`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With vanilla JS:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.delivery').forEach((e) => {
  var date = e.getAttribute('data-date');
  if (date != null && date.includes('Tomorrow')) {
    e.innerHTML+='<div>50p</div>';
  } else {
    e.innerHTML+='<div>FREE</div>';
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="delivery" data-date="Tomorrow"></div>
<div class="delivery" data-date="Today"></div>
<div class="delivery" data-date="Yesterday"></div>
```

With jQuery:

```js
$('.delivery').each(function() {
  var date = $(this).attr('data-date');
  if (date != null && date.includes('Tomorrow')) {
    $(this).append('<div>50p</div>');
  } else {
    $(this).append('<div>FREE</div>');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="delivery" data-date="Tomorrow"></div>
<div class="delivery" data-date="Today"></div>
<div class="delivery" data-date="Yesterday"></div>
```

Comment: @Weirdali Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Ignore `css`, it's  just for representational purpose only.

```js
const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll(".delivery")];

const result = elements.forEach(el => {
  const doesDataAttrExist = el.dataset.date && el.dataset.date.includes("Tomorrow");
  const element = document.createElement("div");

  if (doesDataAttrExist) {
    element.textContent = "50p";
    el.appendChild(element);
  } else {
    element.textContent = "free";
    el.appendChild(element);
  }
})
```

```css
div.delivery {
  background: lightgray;
  padding: .5rem;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: .25rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div[data-date] {
  background: teal;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="delivery" data-date="Tomorrow">1</div>
<div class="delivery">2</div>
<div class="delivery" data-date="Tomorrow">3</div>
<div class="delivery">4</div>
<div class="delivery">5</div>
<div class="delivery" data-date="Tomorrow">6</div>
<div class="delivery">7</div>
<div class="delivery">8</div>
<div class="delivery" data-date="Tomorrow">9</div>
<div class="delivery">10</div>
```